# How to change the shell used in code runner?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have `nodejs` installed and I can access it in my default shell (bash).

The problem is that when I try to run a file it tries to open it with `/bin/sh` and thus it says `/bin/sh: node: command not found`

The problem disappears when I set in configuration `run in integrated terminal` as I have set the default shell for the terminal to `bash`.

How to change the default shell used in the code runner to `bash` so that I can run the file?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found to your same problem is to make code runner run into the vscode integrated terminal.

My settings.json

```json
"code-runner.executorMapByGlob": {
    "*.ts": "ts-node --esm $fullFileName",
},
"code-runner.runInTerminal": true
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it stopped happening when opened vs code on bash, in that scenario code runner runs with bash, so probably you should take a look what starts the vs code and how.

If your problem is that [sh doesn't have the same path as bash](https://superuser.com/a/938087) just add to the /etc/profile.d a file with the following code and should work:

```
if [ -n "${BASH_VERSION}" ]; then
    # include ~/.bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "${HOME}/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "${HOME}/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```